# NSSharingService customize item list depending on chosen service

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to add some basic sharing functionality in my app.
At first I found the `NSSharingServicePicker` class which already implements the sharing menu and the possibility to specify a delegate for the sharing service.
The problem with this solution is that I was not able to specify different kind of items for different services.
For example: I want to share an ''object'' with both emails and Facebook. But on facebook I only want to post a ''title'' property, while on email I want to post the object completely.

So I thought to implement myself the menu and show it using `NSPopUpButton`. Now I have all the functionality I need: because I can call `performWithItems:` on a `NSSharingService` I can specify the items.
But... of course there is a but... The sharing menu can be embedded in different windows. And there can be more then one window on screen at the same time, so I do not know how to handle the delegate for the `NSSharingService` class. Currently each window has a menu object which creates and manages its own array of services. But in this way the opening of the window is very slow (it is not acceptable from a usability point of view). I think this is due to the creation every time of the `NSArray` of `NSSharingService` objects. If I switch to a `static` array I do not know how to handle the delegate..

Does someone have some ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. In the end the performance issue was not caused by the `NSSharingService` menu.
Nevertheless I completely rewrote the component.

I created a singleton class which is responsible of posting the ''objects''. Furthermore it provides a method to create the menu (each time a different menu..).

Now each window (controller) ask the component for a menu and show it. When the user selects an option the window (controller) is the delegate and it knows which object is showing and has to share. So it asks the sharing component to share it with the chosen service.

The only difficult part is how to handle the delegate of the `NSSharingService` classes. I need more information than the input arguments passed from the delegate method (this information is known only when I call `performWithItems:`). So what I did is to save the array of items I'm sharing as a key in a dictionary (to be precise an `NSCache`, with no limits for now) and the information I need later as a value. In the delegate methods (both sharing succeeded and failed) I retrieve the information and remove the object from the cache.
I don't know if this is a good solution.. if someone has some other ideas I am open to suggestions.